# Socket chat room made with Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, tcp, chat

This is a real live chatroom that I have made with Tkinter

I posted a question before about making a chatroom but the problem that I had with that one was that only one user could connect to the server so I restarted and have made this one. I just want suggestions on how I can improve it.

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

## Server.py

```
import socket, threading
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
addresses = {}
print(host)
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True
def handle_client(conn):
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % data
        conn.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
        msg = "%s has joined the chat" % data
        broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
        clients[conn] = data
        while True:
            found = False
            response = 'Number of People Online\n'
            msg1 = conn.recv(1024) 

            if msg1 != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
                broadcast(msg1, data+": ")
            else:
                conn.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
                conn.close()
                del clients[conn]
                broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % data, "utf8"))
                break
    except:
        print("%s has left the chat." % data)
def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)


while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    conn.send("Enter username: ".encode("utf8"))
    print("%s:%s has connected." % addr)
    addresses[conn] = addr
    threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn,)).start()
```

## Client.py

```
import socket,threading,tkinter
host = input("Enter server name: ")
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = (host,port)
def echo_data(sock):
   while True:
      try:
         msg = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
         msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
      except OSError:
         break



def send(event=None):
   msg = my_msg.get() 
   my_msg.set("")
   s.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
   if msg == "{quit}":
      s.close()
      top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chat Room")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  
my_msg.set("Type your messages here.")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

address = (host,port)
s.connect(address)

threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args = (s,)).start()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: how about [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html)?

Comment: `data = conn.recv(1024)` I don't speak Python but if this limits the number of characters that can be received it's going to be a problem.  Look into some sort of streaming (character oriented) interface for sockets, trying to deal with buffers and buffer sizes directly is just going to be a headache.

Comment: `threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args...` Launching one thread per person connected is wasteful and will limit the scaleability of your server.  Look into implementing your net task with one thread: https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice snippet which makes it useful for teaching! Here are some points:

## Make imports explicit

Though `import socket, threading` is valid in Python, importing in two lines improves readability

```
import socket
import threading
```

## Two lines after imports

Add two lines after imports. From this:

```
import socket
import threading
host = socket.gethostname()
...
```

to this:

```
import socket
import threading


host = socket.gethostname()
...
```

## Constants in caps

`port = 4000` should be `PORT = 4000`

## Use string formatting

From this:

```
"%s has left the chat." % data
```

to this:

```
"{} has left the chat.".format(data)
```

In case of curly braces, you escape using `{{}}` as in the following case:

```
'Welcome {}! If you ever want to quit, type {{quit}} to exit.'.format(data)
```

## Broadcast before handle_client

Since in `handle_client` you use `broadcast`, define it first

```
def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    ...

def handle_client(conn):
    ...
```

## Add a message function

enclose:

```
bytes(msg, "utf8")
```

in a function called `message`:

```
def message(text):
    return bytes(text, "utf8")
```

then it becomes neater to use:

```
broadcast(message('hi'))
```

## More explicit messages:

- 1) Server message

When first connecting, the server console states for me:

```
jPC
Server is ready...
```

And then when running clients, you get asked:

```
Enter server name:
```

I had to deduce that jPC is my server name. Modifying to the following might be more explicit:

```
Server name: jPC
Server is ready...
```

- 2) Enter username

`Enter username in the textbox` might be a better message. Coupled with the fact that you did not use a placeholder for the entry, users are confused.

- 3) Quiting without username

If someone quits without setting a username the server says:

```
{quit} has left the chat.
```

Adding a default id for clients might be better

```
{
    '<id2>': {
                'username': None,
                'connection_ip': '192.168.56.1:50325'
    },
    '<id2>': ...
}
```

you can use the uuid module for id or use the ip itself as id

## Add placeholder effect

Add a placeholder effect by adding the line:

```
entry_field.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: entry_field.delete('0', 'end'))
```

Setting the font color to gray completes the effect.

## Miscellaneous

- Use snake case for variables. `serverRunning` becomes `server_running`
- Use a geometry manager like grid for better display